# How i can view all inserted data in ms access form as a table

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have access application that insert data from ms access form to sql server. 
How i can view all inserted data in ms access form as a table?

Comment: have a look at a how to where you can see all function graphical illustrated. it´s a very basic question and every one could solve it. give it a try by yourself. no time for this.

Comment: Take a look at this. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-or-link-to-data-in-an-SQL-Server-database-a5a3b4eb-57b9-45a0-b732-77bc6089b84e

Answer (score 0):

Change the form to *DateSheetView* - either from the band or in the property sheet of the form.